# ObjectFactory and MyBatis, mapping result into JAXBElement<XmlGregorianCalendar>

Tags: java, xml, types, jaxb, mybatis

I am running MyBatis in apache-camel.

The result from the query contains some data in jdbcType="DATE" format. I wrote my custom ObjectTypeHandler which handles conversion between SQL date and XMLGregorianCalendar date type that I am using to set data into JAXB object (generate from xsd scheme).

The problem is that not all the fields in JAXB class accept raw XMLGregorianCalendar value, some of them defined in such manner that they need JAXBElement.

I can use ObjectFactory instance to solve this, but then I would need to write custom ObjectTypeHandler for every field that takes JAXBElement as input (as they have their own create* method in ObjectFactory) and there are many of them. It sounds like a lot of boilerplate and duplicated code.

Is it possible to handle it more graciously?

Comment: Why don't you you use global bindings (in xjb file) when generate JAXB objects for it? I guess XJC compiler will handle it properly.

Comment: @Vadim can you link to how global bindings are used?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using @Vadim recommendation:

Just define `xjb` file (with `generateElementProprety` set to `false` to avoid generation of `JAXBElement` wrappers) and supply it to `XJC` compiler during POJO generation from `XSD` scheme.

For example:

bindings.xjb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Start XJC compiler via command:

```
xjc *.xsd -d ../../java -b bindings.xjb
```

This example generate POJO files into `../../java` directory from scheme files (`*.xsd`) located in working directory using additional settings from `bindings.xjb` file.

Thanks, @Vadim, for pointing into right direction!