# Proper ObjectFactory in MyBatis TypeHandler

Tags: spring, mybatis, spring-ws

I'm creating a project in Spring-ws with MyBatis.
I have many web services definitions in xsd.
Spring is creating POJO classes based on xsd.

The problem is that in xsd I have fields that have parameter `nillable="true"`

like this:
`<xs:element name="numericParam" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>`

That field in generated POJO looks like this:
`protected JAXBElement<Integer> numericParam;`

I want to create custom `TypeHandler` in MyBatis config, to handle `JAXBElement<Integer>` types, but how can I know which `ObjectFactory` to use.

Is it possible to know which mapper is calling my custom TypeHandler? In TypeHandler all I have is column name.

Comment: Why is it important to know which mapper the handler is used in? Doesn't the conversion between database column and object field depend only on the type types of the column and the field?

Comment: Yes, it suppose to depend only by the type of column and field. Unfortunately to create object `JAXBElement<Integer>` I need to know exactly what is the name of that field and in which model it is located. It has to be created like this: `new ObjectFactory().createNumericParam(value)`. I have many model definitions divided logically in multiple xsd’s and each xsd has it’s own `ObjectFactory` which is responsible for creating only it’s own fields. Not knowing the current mapper (or at least endpoint) in `TypeHandler` I have no way of choosing right `ObjectFactory`

Comment: Would the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922539/objectfactory-and-mybatis-mapping-result-into-jaxbelementxmlgregoriancalendar work for you?

Comment: I have tried this, but it's not working in my case. I'm getting some strange errors while generating POJO: `NameConverter is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces`. I think it's because I'm using `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible currently (version 3.4.6) in mybatis. No information about the context (like enclosing type or mapper method) is passed to handler.

If you do want to use jaxb generated types you would need to create a handler per field (of cause it make sense to have common base that would implement all the logic).